# Spring Data REST rename resource

Tags: spring, rest

The following the JSON representation of a GClass as generated by default with Spring Data REST.

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/classes/1"
    },
    "gClass" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/classes/1"
    }
  }
}
```

It's a class's reference to itself (that's fine) and then that same information again but with the property type included this time. The issue I have is that I can't figure out how to change "gClass" to "class".

From the Spring Data REST reference doc:

> For every association of the domain type, we expose links named after the association property. You can customize this behavior by using @RestResource on the property.

This works for me on properties in entity classes, but not on references to itself. I can't, for example, annotate my class (GClass) with:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CLASSES")
@RestResource(rel="class")
public class GClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long classId;

    public GClass() {}

    public long getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }

    public void setClassId(int classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }
}
```

The repository is a simple JpaRespository. I can change both it's relation name and path name without issue.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "classes", path = "classes")
public interface GClassRepository extends JpaRepository<GClass, Long>{}
```

I can create a RepresentationModelProcessor bean that removes the link from every EntityModel and re-creates the link with a new rel name. That solution seems as though that's a very involved process for a pretty standard piece of customization. What am I missing?